# Finding the probability that a device lasts 12 or more months.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be lifetime components of devices with pdf $f(x)=\frac{4x^3 e^{-(x/2)^4}}{16}$

If two components fail, the device fails.

**NOTE**: The problem didn't specify but I'm assuming the pdf is a pdf of the lifetime of one component in years.

**a) What is the probability that the device lasts 12 months or more?**

$P$(1 component lasts 12 months or more)

$$=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x^3 e^{-(x/2)^4}}{4} dx\approx 0.9394$$

So $P$(1 component fails within 12 months)=$1-0.9394=0.0606$

I think that the number of components that fail is binomial so

$P$(device lasts 12 months or more) = $P$(0 components fail)$+P$(1 component fails)

$=(0.9394)^n+n(0.0606)(0.9394)^{n-1}$

**b) What is the probability that the device lasts 12 months after going to 5 months?**

$P$(device lasts 12 months or more | device lasts 5 months or more)

The probability that one component lasts 5 months or more is

$$=\int_{5/12}^{\infty} \frac{x^3 e^{-(x/2)^4}}{4} dx \approx 0.99812$$

So probability that one component fails within 5 months is $0.00188$.

Therefore $P$(that device lasts 5 months or more)$=P$(0 out of n components fail within 5 months)$+P$(1 out of n components fail within 5 months)

$=(0.99812)^n+n(0.00188)(0.99812)^{n-1}$

$P$(device lasts 12 months or more | device lasts 5 months or more)
$=P$(device lasts 12 months or more, device lasts 5 months or more)/ $P$(device lasts 5 months or more)

$= P$(device lasts 12 months or more)/P(device lasts 5 months or more)

$=\frac{(0.9394)^n+n(0.0606)(0.9394)^{n-1}}{(0.99812)^n+n(0.00188)(0.99812)^{n-1}}$

Are my solutions correct? Is there an easier way to do these?

Comment: What is the main question?

Comment: @openspace sorry, I just want to know if my solution is correct and if there is an easier way to do this, i updated the post

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're asked the conditional probability here, P(T>=12 | T>=5) where T is the time of the breakdown (in months). The answer should be thus in the form
P(T>=12 and T>=5)/P(T>=5)=P(T>=12)/P(T>=5), so it looks **correct**.

Comment: Yes I found the conditional probability for part b). is there something incorrect about how I did it?

Comment: @user8290579 You didn't say anything about what that last fraction is, so it's not obvious you mean it to be the conditional probability and the final answer.

Comment: @aschepler i'm sorry I will clarify it now in my post